# Is there a numpy way to reduce arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this numpy array which is a concatention of other numpy arrays

```
array([array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]]),
       array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]]),
       array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]]),
       array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]]),
       array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]]),
       array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])], dtype=object)
```

its current shape is `(6,)`. what I want is this with a shape `(6,6)`

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]], dtype=object)
```

Is there a numpy way to solve this problem or do I have to loop through the arrays and append it?

Comment: `np.vstack(a)`/`np.concatenate(a)`/`np.stack(a,axis=-1)[0]`?

Comment: Your 1d is an object dtype array of other arrays.  `concatenate` treats it as a list of arrays, which it can join on the axis of your choosing (the inner arrays are 2d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the display is accurate, and the array really is (6,), then we have to recreate it with:

```
In [27]: array=np.array
In [28]: alist = [array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]]),
    ...:        array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]]),
    ...:        array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]]),
    ...:        array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]]),
    ...:        array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]]),
    ...:        array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])]
    ...:        
In [29]: A = np.empty((6,),object)
In [30]: A
Out[30]: array([None, None, None, None, None, None], dtype=object)
In [31]: A[:]=alist
In [32]: A
Out[32]: 
array([array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]]),
       array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]]),
       array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]]),
       array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]]),
       array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]]),
       array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])], dtype=object)
```

`reshape` does not work:

```
In [33]: A.reshape(6,6)
...
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 6 into shape (6,6)
```

But the array can be treated as a list, and given to `concatenate`:

```
In [34]: np.concatenate(A, axis=1)
Out[34]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,
         0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
In [35]: np.concatenate(A, axis=0)
Out[35]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Concatenate on the list works just as well: `np.concatenate(alist, axis=0)`

I should note that the resulting array is dtype `float`, not `object`.  It could be converted with `astype`, but who would want that?

---

Simple copy-n-paste produces a 3d array, since the outer `array` ignores the inner division and creates as high-a-dimensional array as it can:

```
In [37]: array([array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]]),
    ...:        array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]]),
    ...:        array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]]),
    ...:        array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]]),
    ...:        array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]]),
    ...:        array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])])       
Out[37]: 
array([[[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]],

       [[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]],
        ...
       [[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]]])
In [38]: _.shape
Out[38]: (6, 1, 6)
```

So we need to careful how we recreate cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
my_array = my_array.reshape(6,6)
```

It works with the above array when pasted as is as it will remove the third dimension. Other methods like vstack and concatenate as shown on @Divikar comment above should work as well for this purpose

Comment: What's the shape of the pasted array?  1d or 3d?